# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sporadically Failing Health Checks

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

has anyone else seen sporadic health checks failing on their elastic beanstalk applications?

I'm using ELB to serve a GraphQL API. I'm using running the docker configuration on a single t2.micro instance with monitoring interval set for 1 minute. It is set to scale up to 4 instances on heavy load. Datastore uses Amazon RDS (PostgreSQL, non-publicly available, db.t2.micro).

The following are the latest values from my ELB Events page:

```
2018-05-23 08:24:11 UTC-0600    INFO
Environment health has transitioned from Severe to Ok.

2018-05-23 08:23:11 UTC-0600    WARN
Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Severe. None of the instances are sending data.

2018-05-21 06:28:13 UTC-0600    INFO
Environment health has transitioned from Severe to Ok.

2018-05-21 06:27:13 UTC-0600    WARN
Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Severe. 85.7 % of the requests are erroring with HTTP 4xx.

2018-05-18 14:10:51 UTC-0600    INFO
Environment health has transitioned from Severe to Ok.
```

I have occasionally seen the HTTP 4XX warnings since I deployed my application a few months ago. I have never seen `None of the instances are sending data` warning before. I don't see any matching 4XX errors in my application logs.

Not sure if this is normal, or if I have something misconfigured. Amazon Compute advertises an SLA level of 99.99% found in their Service Commitment section [here](https://aws.amazon.com/compute/sla/).
I should expect to see downtimes in the range of:

- Daily: 8.6s
- Weekly: 1m 0.5s
- Monthly: 4m 23.0s
- Yearly: 52m 35.7s

I do not see any errors in my external health check (I use UptimeRobot, which polls my API's health endpoint every five minutes and searches for a keyword). I don't see any errors in my application logs.

If anyone else has seen flickering health status and found a way to mitigate this (or at least why this is happening), I would appreciate some advice. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have frequently seen the one-minute failures on low-traffic instances, such as testing environments. Every time I've investigated, the 4XX errors were from a port scanner or some other malicious requests. Since traffic on non-prod instances is low, it doesn't take much to trigger "85.7 % of the requests" - that could be as few as six out of seven requests, for example.

You might see the 4XX errors in your ELB logs if they aren't showing up in your application logs. ELB logging is disabled by default, but you can turn it on and log to S3.

The simplest approach would be to restrict access to your application by whitelisting IPs in your security group. If your application needs to be public-facing, however, then you have a few options for addressing the problem:

1. If the requests are coming from a single IP address, you can block it using an ACL in your VPC.
2. If the requests are coming from multiple IP addresses, you might be able to block them if there is any consistent pattern, such as what URI they're attempting to access, the associated User Agent, or the like. You'd need to enable WAF, however.
3. Just ignore the warnings - they're most likely harmless, and once you have more traffic, they'll blend in with the rest of the noise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Brian. Perhaps I do not understand the health check then. Isn't the health check/monitor an internal evaluation and unrelated to external traffic?

Comment: The ELB itself performs a heartbeat-style health check, where a particular URI or port is pinged periodically. ElasticBeanstalk uses several factors to determine environment health, however. One of those factors is the percentage of bad (4XX/5XX) requests versus good (2XX) requests.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

While Brian is correct about the cause—I see this daily from port scanners—and lists some sensible options, just noting that Elastic Beanstalk now has a relatively new rule to ignore 4xx errors as another option, per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-rules.html

A caveat is that you may miss 4xx errors from configuration issues or application errors.